# How create page for users to log ideas?

Tags: submit

I am new to SharePoint and I need to do the following :

1. Create a page with a form to allow users to log free text entries for suggestions for process improvements
2. Ability to attach files
3. Ability to attach embed URL’s
4. On save entry / submission page will send an email with details of the entry added to a specific email address

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Many thanks,
Mark.

EDIT 23/06/2015 - I have researched Lists and it looks like a good option but i do not appear to have the "Insert New List" option when i check out the page for edit, i only see the options in the attached image - do i need certain permissions setting on the site ?.

[image]

Thanks again,
Mark.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a list for that. Just give the list the columns that the form should have. Users are then able to fill in and attach files. Then you can use SharePoint Designer to create a workflow for sending e-mails.

Here is a video for creating the workflow:
[Click me](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDoQtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DnNxD82KiUhQ&ei=Fq2CVfyZGsWPU9XogdgG&usg=AFQjCNE-qmrVprhy3oQtoZ9bXyjTfPis5w&sig2=27DQlPu7WM_tDFkfnFhKiw&bvm=bv.96041959,d.d24)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the custom list is your option for that, as it could have needed fields (form) to fill-in, attachments and you could configure workflow on it to send emails (with sharepoint designer).
The new list you can create from settings -> add an app:

[image]

and choose "Custom list".

In the created List settings you will already have a Title, so you can add more columns, like:

"IdeaDescription" -> multiline text field

"SampleURL" -> hyperlink or picture field

and so on.

Comment: Many thanks for that martusha, it has got me started on the right path.